# Is there a way to combine some groups of css selectors with a precedence logic (group vs group)?

Tags: css, css-selectors, is-pseudo-class

I think this is a strange question and I didn't even really know how to write it..

I have to filter a big list of elements using querySelectorAll(). I would need, but really don't know if it's possible, to do something like this (fake code):

```
[data-attr1=a][data-attr2=b]([data-attr3*=c], [data-attr4*=d])
```

Please note the brackets, and also that comma is only inside brackets.
In other words, I would like that my elements are filtered like:

*"All the resulting elements must have both `data-attr1=a AND data-attr2=b`, `AND` must also have `data-attr3*=c OR data-attr4*=d`"*.

Is that some way possible? Is there any syntax suitable? Maybe it would be enough something like this, but really verbose:

```
[data-attr1=a][data-attr2=b][data-attr3*=c], 
[data-attr1=a][data-attr2=b][data-attr4*=d]
```

Right? Any better syntax?

Comment: There is no possibility. you can't write abbreviated

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't one. If it's acceptable, you can make 2 `querySelectorAll()` with conditions you wrote, concat results and remove duplicates (using Set maybe).

Comment: Not exactly guys, I've just answered below.

Answer (score 2):

I've just found an answer: I can use the 'new' :is() or :where() syntax:

```
[data-attr1=a][data-attr2=b]:is([data-attr3*=c], [data-attr4*=d])
```

That is going to select exactly what I was searching for. It also works as js selector.

```js
const filtered = document.querySelectorAll("[data-prop2='value2'][data-prop3='value2']:is([data-prop1*='value2'],[data-prop1*='value3'])");

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
[data-prop2='value2'][data-prop3='value2']:is([data-prop1*='value2'],[data-prop1*='value3']){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div data-prop1="value1,value2" data-prop2="value1">elem 1</div>
<div data-prop1="value1" data-prop2="value1">elem 2</div>
<div data-prop1="value2" data-prop2="value2" data-prop3="value1">elem 3</div>
<div data-prop1="value1,value2,value3" data-prop2="value2" data-prop3="value2">elem 4</div>
<div data-prop1="value3" data-prop2="value2" data-prop3="value2">elem 4</div>
```